# Remix session values don't persist across pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I'm making a site using Remix where I'd like to persist session values across pages. I think the issue lies in the getSession request, as the values do not persist across requests to the same page. I have implemented a session cookie in `sessions.ts`:

```js
const { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } =
    createCookieSessionStorage<SessionData, SessionFlashData>(
        {
            //cookie options to create a cookie
            cookie: {
                name: "__session",
                maxAge: 1200,
                path: "/",
                sameSite: "none",
                secure: true,
                secrets: ["surprise"]

            },
        }
    );
```

On one page I set a value and log it out and receive the expected value

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
    const session = await getSession(
        request.headers.get("Cookie")
    );
    session.set("token", "abc123")
    var data = { "count": 2 }
    console.log(session.get("token"))
    return json(data, {
        headers: {
            "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
        },
    });
};
```

however when i try to access the value in a different page, the value is undefined

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );
  var data = { "abc": 442 }
  console.log(session.get("token"))
  return json(data, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });

  return null


};
```

I'm very new to remix and react so appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was to do with the `sameSite` option and `Secure` options.
as I am working locally, Secure must be set to false which means sameSite must be either lax or strict

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Ov_.01 is correct. I had to change my `secure` from `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` to an explicit `false`. This was my full cookie that allowed sessions to persist for me locally.

```
const sessionStorage = createCookieSessionStorage({
  cookie: {
    // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    secure: false, // TODO: local session doesn't persist when using process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    secrets: [process.env.SESSION_SECRET],
    sameSite: 'lax',
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    httpOnly: true
  }
})
```