# Remix session is not persisting on page refresh

Tags: node.js, session, remix.run

I am having an issue where Remix is not persisting the session when the page is refreshed or the user navigates to a new child route. I have looked through other issues and unfortunately, the following is the same problem but the solution doesn't work for me:

[Remix session values don't persist across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385267/remix-session-values-dont-persist-across-pages)

**app/sessions.ts**

```
// app/sessions.ts
import { createCookieSessionStorage } from "@remix-run/node"; // or cloudflare/deno

type SessionData = {
  userId: string;
};

type SessionFlashData = {
  error: string;
};

const { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } =
  createCookieSessionStorage<SessionData, SessionFlashData>(
    {
      // a Cookie from `createCookie` or the CookieOptions to create one
      cookie: {
        name: "__session",

        // all of these are optional
        domain: "remix.run",
        // Expires can also be set (although maxAge overrides it when used in combination).
        // Note that this method is NOT recommended as `new Date` creates only one date on each server deployment, not a dynamic date in the future!
        //
        // expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60_000),
        path: "/account",
        sameSite: "lax",
        secrets: ["xxxx"],
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
      },
    }
  );

export { getSession, commitSession, destroySession };
```

**app/routes/account._index.tsx**

```
import type { ActionFunctionArgs, MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Link, json, redirect, useActionData, useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { JwtPayload, jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode'
import { UserProps, createUser } from "~/models/user";
import { commitSession, getSession } from "~/session";
import { createSession, isSession } from "@remix-run/node";

/* 
  JWT
  {
    iss: 'https://accounts.google.com',
   // ...
    locale: 'en',
    iat: 1709314101,
    exp: 1709317701,
    jti: 'xxx'
}
*/

interface googleJwtToken {
  iss: string;
  azp: string;
  aud: string;
  sub: string;
  email: string;
  email_verified: boolean;
  nbf: number;
  name: string;
  picture: string;
  given_name: string;
  family_name: string;
  locale: string;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
  jti: string;
}

export async function action({
  request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs){

  const token = await request.formData();

  //Decode the JWT token
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token.get('credential') as string) as googleJwtToken;

  const user: UserProps = {
    id: decodedToken?.email,
    email: decodedToken.email,
    name: decodedToken.name,
    picture: decodedToken.picture,
    given_name: decodedToken.given_name,
    family_name: decodedToken.family_name,
    locale: decodedToken.locale
  }

  const res = await createUser(user);

  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );

  session.set("userId", decodedToken.email);

  json(decodedToken, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });

  return decodedToken;

}

export async function loader({
  request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs ){

  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );

  console.log(session.data)
  
  // Login succeeded, send them to the home page.
  return json(session, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });

}

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
  return [
    { title: "My Account | Webmeau" },
  ];
};

export default function Account() {

  const data: googleJwtToken | undefined = useActionData();


  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Account</h1>
      <Link to='/account/messages' replace state={ { contextData: 'test' }}>Messages</Link>
      <h2>{ data && `Welcome ${data?.name || ""}` }</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

No matter what I seem to try to do, I am only able to get the userId set in the session on the action route after the session is committed but any subsequent GET request fails to get any session.

Answer (score 0):

So it may be my lack of remix understanding but, I was able to get it to work by moving my loader function to a new "auth" route and redirect from there. Seems to be working like a gem now.

**app/routes/auth.tsx**

```
import { ActionFunctionArgs, json, redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { UserProps, createUser } from "~/models/user";
import { commitSession, getSession } from "~/session";

interface googleJwtToken {
    iss: string;
    azp: string;
    aud: string;
    sub: string;
    email: string;
    email_verified: boolean;
    nbf: number;
    name: string;
    picture: string;
    given_name: string;
    family_name: string;
    locale: string;
    iat: number;
    exp: number;
    jti: string;
  }
  
  export async function action({
    request,
  }: ActionFunctionArgs){
  
    const token = await request.formData();
  
    //Decode the JWT token
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token.get('credential') as string) as googleJwtToken;
  
    const user: UserProps = {
      id: decodedToken?.email,
      email: decodedToken.email,
      name: decodedToken.name,
      picture: decodedToken.picture,
      given_name: decodedToken.given_name,
      family_name: decodedToken.family_name,
      locale: decodedToken.locale
    }
  
    const res = await createUser(user);
  
    const session = await getSession(
      request.headers.get("Cookie")
    );
  
    session.set("userId", decodedToken.email);
  
    console.log(session.data)
  
    return redirect('/account', {
      headers: {
        "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
      },
    });;
  
  }
```

**/app/routes/account._index.tsx**

```
import type { ActionFunctionArgs, MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Link, json, redirect, useActionData, useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { JwtPayload, jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode'
import { UserProps, createUser } from "~/models/user";
import { commitSession, getSession } from "~/session";
import { createSession, isSession } from "@remix-run/node";

export async function loader({
  request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs ){

  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );

  console.log(session.data)
  
  // Login succeeded, send them to the home page.
  return json(session, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });

}

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
  return [
    { title: "My Account | Webmeau" },
  ];
};

export default function Account() {

  const user: any = useLoaderData();
  const { userId } = user.data;
 
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Account</h1>
      <h2>{`Welcome ${userId}`}</h2>
      <Link to='/account/messages' replace state={ { contextData: 'gilbert.a.comeau' }}>Messages</Link>

    </>
  );
}
```